# Script to automate git tasks

Tags: linux, git, bash, netbeans

I'm new to git (old dog), I have a gitbucket server running as a remote repository. I am using Linux and Netbeans (not CLI, but I am not averse to using it).
The tasks that I need to automate are as follows (which I assume are standard):

1. Pull master
2. Create branch
3. Make changes in IDE
4. Commit, write a suitable message
5. Switch to master
6. Git > remote > pull
7. Switch to local branch
8. Rebase, choosing second option
9. Switch to master
10. Merge revision (select local branch)
11. Push

Since I do all of these repeatedly, I thought that there might be a way to  automate these tasks, maybe a bash script? The script would perform tasks 4 to 11. All of my experience thus far has been using the GUI, not the CLI.

My efforts thus far have yielded me this script, but some of the GUI commands don't seem to match to CLI commands:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Usage: ./git_script.sh "commit_message" "local_branch"
cd /var/www/html/project
git commit -m "$1"
# switch to master
git checkout "$2" # does this pull from master?
# switch to local branch $2
git rebase master
# switch to master
git merge "$2"
git push
```

Comment: `git checkout <branch>` just switch the local branch. Do `git pull origin <branch>` to pull the `<branch>` from origin. (what do you mean by pull from `master`? use `git merge` if you want to merge current branch to some other branch)

Comment: I'd strongly advise against this sort of automation. It seems like you're probably used to SVN or some other tool, and you're trying to make git behave like it, rather than learn to work with git. As with any version control tool, actions like rebasing and merging can potentially result in conflicts which will need manual intervention - if that happens part-way through your script, you'll very likely find that it's hard to tell what went wrong and why, and just a single instance of that will eat up way more time than this script saves you in a lifetime!